# Creating a 2D array of a class in Java (developing a chess)

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a chess library in Java and focusing on the Object-Oriented design of it. I idea is to create a class called Tile, which contains a coordinate (x, y), boolean isOccupied, and the information of the piece that it contains.

It looks like this:

```
public abstract class Tile {

    boolean isOccupied;
    int x, y;
    Piece piece;

    Tile(boolean isOccupied, int x, int y, Piece piece) {

        this.isOccupied = isOccupied;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.piece = piece;

    }

    //Returns the piece on the tile - will be implemented in the subclass
    public abstract Piece getPiece();

    //Places a piece on the tile - will be implemented in the subclass
    public abstract void placePiece(Piece piece);

    public abstract void removePiece();

}
```

Then, on my Piece class, I am trying to make a method that checks whether the destination of the piece is a valid location. The function declaration might look something like:

```
public abstract boolean isValidLocation(Tile[][] board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY);
```

I am expecting to create a 2D-array of a class Tile named board and set the starting coordinate and the ending coordinate and do the calculation on each Piece subclass to see if the target location is valid.

My questions are:

1) Is it possible to create a 2D array of a class (Tile) like this and make it work as I expect?

2) Will I have to add a function that generates a 'n x n' Tile array anywhere in my classes?

3) Will there be a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Do you really need a `Tile` class? Wouldn't an array of `Piece` be better, with empty elements being free squares.

Comment: Wouldn't I need a Tile or a Board class if I want to extend it to a GUI in the future?

Comment: Well a `Board` class would be a good container for the array, but neither are required per se for the GUI. A `JPanel` subclass doing custom painting based on the array would be enough. Modeling each tile and piece as a GUI element is kinda sketchy, although I'm sure you're thinking that a `GridLayout` is the perfect use case for a chessboard (it's not).

Comment: Thanks again. But wouldn't we be unable to decide the shape of the board without having a Tile or a Board class?

Comment: You didn't include anything in the question to suggest a different shaped board than a regular one. In fact, I'd suggest you try to get it working with a regular board before you start doing any weird Star Trek 3D chess things. Walk before you run etc.

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry for not stating that in the question. So, are you saying that specifying the shape of the board will be unable without the TIle or a Board class?

Comment: I don't really see `Tile` as a very useful class. The `Board` class could take care of the shape of the board, as well as contain functionality related to the actual board (checking valid moves, drawing itself, etc.) while the `Piece` class would be then responsible for movement type, etc. It leaves very little to do for a `Tile`. But as always with program design, YMMV. I wouldn't create a `Tile` class until I'd find out it's needed.

Comment: So, the Board class would take care of the shape of the board and the Piece class would have locations?

Comment: I don't know why a `Piece` should explicitly know it's location. The `Board` should obviously know the locations of all pieces. In a simple scenario, this could be the `Board` having a `Piece[][]`. There are many ways to skin a cat though, and the better defined your goal is, the easier it is to implement it. If you want to create differently shaped boards, magical tiles or other non-conventional chess things, it's an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

To anwser your questions:

1) Yes it is possible and will probably work as expected

2) In your constructor you can initialize the 2D-array, just for every x,y fill it with an empty tile.

3) A simpler way to do this could be to just make a 2D-array of your `Piece` class.
It would be something like `Piece[x][y]`.
You can then just set a location to a `Piece`, when the location is `null` it means that there is no `Piece` in that location and it would be a valid move.

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't I need a Tile or a Board class if I want to extend it to a GUI in the future?

Comment: Also about your answer to question (2), if I initialize the 2D Tile array in my constructor, will it just automatically generate a 2D Tile array whenever I initialize a Tile object? If so, will it just be better to create another class called Board and do this?

Comment: @user6792790 Not at all. All you need to have in order to create a GUI of your chess game, is : the piece and its coordinate. Having a 2D array of Piece solve both of those requirement.

Comment: It is also a valid move to move your own piece on top of the enemy one.

Comment: @Asew Then, how are we supposed to decide the shape of the board? The chess board does not necessarily have to be a 8x8 square.

Comment: @user6792790 You just need a class with the attribute `private Piece[][] board`. In the constructor, you can decide of the board's size.

Comment: So, are you saying the I will be able to set the size of the board freely by setting the Piece to null in specific positions?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go for using just a Piece class, and a Board class. I dont see why you would introduce a tile class.

The board holds an array of pieces, like this:

```
ArrayList<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<Piece>();
```

In the board class you can implement a render(); method that will iterate over both arraylists, asking Piece.location, .player (black/white), .type (pawn, king, tower etc.) to be able to render the board.

The other thing you would implement is board.movePiece() which will try to move a piece's location. Firstly it would ask the piece .isValidLocation, wich will invoke a method on the piece where the piece will indicate wether the move is a valid one. Then after that, its up to the board to see what happens after a piece has been moved (did it hit any other piece? did the game reach check or check-mate?), and then re-render the GUI by invoking its own render() method.

Comment: While its not a bad idea, I don't like the fact that you have to iterate through the entire `ArrayList`of `Piece` to check if there is one at a certain position. A double array  `Piece[][]` makes it way easier.

Comment: @Asew its something that you could argue about, and it depends on how you set up the architecture of your application.
In your scenario you are assuming that its the responsibility of the board to know the location of the pieces. In my scenario im assuming its the responsibility of the pieces to maintain their position.
That way you can ask just 1 piece to redraw itself, and contain all logic for that within the piece without having to access the board object. The location of a chess piece, is a property of a piece, not of the board. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design